# Dynamic custom fields in the Django Admin panel?

Tags: python, json, django, django-admin

I have a number of Custom Fields in the Django Admin panel in which I'd like to be able to add values into and I'm wondering if that's possible to implement.

Currently, I have one Custom Field in use that on the frontend shows "Masses: " and next to it I have a field but it's free text. The other Custom Fields are NULL and do not show on the frontend side. Below is a snippet of the loop which iterates through the items:

```
            {% for field in form %}
                {% for key, value in custom_fields_used.items %}
                    {% if key == field.name %}
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
                                {{ value }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                {{ field }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
```

Below I have also a JSON snippet from that specific table in which the values reside, the Custom Fields are part of the JSON template:

```
  "tenant": {
    "custom_field_1": "Masses:", # this field 
    "custom_field_2": null,
    "custom_field_3": null,
    "custom_field_4": null,
    "custom_field_5": null,
    "custom_field_6": null,
    "custom_field_7": null,
    "custom_field_8": null,
  }
```

I managed to implement a [Multiselect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHm9N.png) in the Admin Panel...However the fields are empty and those fields I want to make so other Admins can add their values into the multiselect, the same goes for the dropdowns that I will implement.

My question is, can those fields be dynamic, e.g can an administrator add their own values and add/remove from that one field? Also if so, can other administrators change/add values using the JSON template the same way?

I have considered a solution using a button or maybe a third party tool like Select2 but I don't think that's what is expected here. Please correct me if I am wrong!